# Problema em código C#

Tags: c#

Alguem sabe qual o problema nesse código abaixo? Está dando o seguinte erro: "O fluxo não é gravável"

```
     TcpListener tcpl = new TcpListener(500);
        tcpl.Start();
        Socket sock = tcpl.AcceptSocket();
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sock);
        BinaryWriter write;


        while (true)
            {


            string Resp = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}",
                "HTTP/1.1 890 FOUND",
                "",
                "<h1>Worked!</h1>"
                );

            write = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            write.Write(Resp);
            write.Close();
            }
        tcpl.Stop();
        sock.Close();
        stream.Close();
```

Comment: Quando sai do laço? E para que esse laço?

Comment: O laço "nunca" sai, é um "servidor" que recebe conexõoes continuamente. Ele serve justamente para nunca parar de receber conexões e respondê-las.

Comment: ok.. mas nesse caso use `socket.Connected` para verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você executa o comando `write.Close();` ele fecha o recurso `NetworkStream stream` e por isso não consegue gravar. Tente:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))){
    writer.Write(Resp);
}
```

ou

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.Default, true))){
    writer.Write(Resp);
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou! : (